# No chipset description after airmon-ng in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I have a world of trouble using aircrack. I would like to know if this missing info has anything to do with the problem.

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng

PHY    Interface    Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       rtl8814au     *****NO VALUES****
```

*** is completely blank under chipset ***

I am using Virtualbox and Kali Linux, my USB adapter is TP-LINK AC1900 Archer T9UH and I have confirmed that it should be fine to use.

Answer (score 1):

First, i would suggest that you run this command:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

If you still don't see the chipset information, then try `airmon-zc`, this should shows the proper driver and chipset.

I am not sure why `airmon-ng` does not! It could be a bug issue in the release, or you have to install/upgrade the proper `airmon-ng` drivers for your chipset.